# How to calculate adjustment (inches) to move 2 corners of a parallelogram over for a perfect rectangle?

Tags: math, geometry

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the amount in inches to move two corners of a Parallelogram over so that all corners are 90 degree right angles with only 4 variables: width, height, diagonal1, diagonal2.

```
public float GetParallelogramToRectangleAdjustment(float width, float height, float diagonal1, float diagonal2);
```

Diagonal1 is the measurement from one corner to the opposite corner, and diagonal2 is the other 2 corners. The direction of the adjustment is already known. I just need to calculate the adjustment in inches (the hard part).

Any ideas?

Comment: I was hoping there was a simple formula. I guess it's not that simple..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem properly:

[image]

```
  p^2 + h^2 = d1^2
  p = Sqrt(d1^2 - h^2)
  x = (w - p) / 2
```